# How do I get the formatted string of logging.LogRecord object

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

I want to print only some INFO log messages to both console and log file. I have created a logger with StreamHandler and FileHandler. I print all messages to File, versus only ERROR and CRITICAL in console. Below is my log configuration.

```
# create logger
self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
self.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Prints only ERROR CRITICAL to stdout
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

# Prints ALL log levels to file
fh = logging.FileHandler(self.logFile, 'w')
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# create formatter
self.formatLogMessage = '[[%(asctime)s]\t[%(levelname)s]\t[%(filename)s]\t[%(funcName)s]\t[%(processName)s]]\t%(message)s'
formatter = logging.Formatter(self.formatLogMessage)

# add formatter
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
ch.setFormatter(formatter)

# add ch to logger
self.logger.addHandler(fh)
self.logger.addHandler(ch)
```

Now logger.info() prints only to file.

Suppose I want to force print some info messages to console. I have written a method - printInfoConsole to print explicitly to console along with log as:

```
# Method to print Info to both log and console
def __printInfoConsole(self, msg, fnName="validate"):
  name = os.path.basename(__file__)
  record = self.logger.makeRecord(self.logger.name,logging.INFO,name,None,msg=msg,args=None,exc_info=None,func=fnName)
  self.logger.handle(record)
  print(record)
```

This prints to log file and console. However, the formatting is incorrect when I do 'print(record') as:

```
<LogRecord: __main__, 20, compare_fusionapps.py, None, "bi_cluster: 'fusion.FADomain.bi_cluster.default.minmaxmemory.main' is not set on target.">
```

Versus in log file as:

```
[[2019:04:11 15:34:11,474       [INFO]  [compare_fusionapp.py]  [validate]]     bi_cluster: 'fusion.FADomain.bi_cluster.default.minmaxmemory.main' is not set on target.
```

I tried record.getMessage(), but that gives only the message, minus the formatting. 
How do I make sure that my console log output matches the log file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to apply a Formatter to the LogRecord.

```
print(formatter.format(record))
```

Answer (score 1):

[Definition of class logging.Formatter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Formatter)

```
class logging.Formatter(fmt=None, datefmt=None, **style='%'**, validate=True, *, defaults=None)
```

You can just set the **'style'** as '{'.